# Debugging TypeScript Node project in WebStorm does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, webstorm, ts-node

I am failing to debug TypeScript Node.js app. When running WebStorm debugger it executes my index.ts file but it does not stop at the breakpoints.

I get in the console:

> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55316/c3ce6255-5746-45a1-bfbf-d7f07d6e84d4
> For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
> Debugger attached.
> Hsswswsello, World! 5
> Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */,
    "outDir": "build" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "rootDir": "src" /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "esModuleInterop": false /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    "resolveJsonModule": true /* Include modules imported with '.json' extension */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "inlineSources": true
  },
  "exclude": ["spec", "build", "node_modules", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "fe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx jest --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "start": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .ts --fix",
    "lint": "prettier --config .prettierrc 'src/**/*.ts' --write"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "npm run lint",
      "npm run lint:check"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.24.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.24.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^8.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^5.0.3",
    "jsdom": "^16.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "prettier-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.37.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.4",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what Node.js version do you use? Please share a screenshot of your run configuration

Comment: Node.js version i  use 14.16.1

Comment: strange... works fine for me. Could you share a screenshot of your run configuration plus a test project the issue can be repeated with?

Comment: i dont know how to add a screenshot here

Comment: you can add it to the question body using the **image** toolbar button